# Core Data Detail View from To-Many relationship

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data

I'm struggling with some aspects of Core Data, namely setting up a UITableView to list data from a to-many relationship.

I have three entities, Teams, TeamDetails and Players:

[image]

In the first view, I list the names of all the teams in the Teams entity, then tapping each cell segues to an intermediate view with buttons to either edit a team's details or edit a team's players. Tapping on a button segues to another UITableView that lists the Team's details or Players.

Listing the TeamDetails works, since it is a one-to-one relationship and a static cell table.

I'm trying to set up a UITableViewController that lists all the players that are associated with the selected team.  So I pass the ManagedObjectContext etc to the table view controller via the segue as shown below:

```
else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ShowPlayersSegue"]){
    NSLog(@"Setting ShowPlayersTVC as a delegate of EditPlayerTVC");
    ShowPlayersTVC *showPlayerTVC = segue.destinationViewController;
    showPlayerTVC.delegate = self;
    showPlayerTVC.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;

    showPlayerTVC.team = self.team;
    showPlayerTVC.player = self.team.playerDetails;
}
```

So, in my showPlayerTVC I want to get the set of players for that specific team, then have a row for each one that shows the playerName attribute as the cell textlabel.text.

I've been reading tutorials and playing around for ages without getting much success.  I think I need to create an array of Player objects from the NSSet, which I can do, but I can't get the UITableview to list the objects.  I'm probably missing something fundamental here, but any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: A.  Have you verified that your concerted array contained proper Players objects.  Nslog a playerName or two, etc.   B.  Show the code of your cellForRowAtIndexPath if you had.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there are some issues with your data model.

The one-to-one to details I do not understand - why not just add attributes to the Team entity? Also, you may want to transform some of these into more flexible relationships, such as a Trainer entity, etc.

Also, your naming is flawed and will lead to programming errors or at least make your code difficult to read. Note the singular / plural confusion. Here is my suggestion for naming your entities / relationships:

```
Team - players <--------------->> team - Player
```

To display data in an a table view you should use `NSFetchedResultsController`. Let the FRC fetch the Player entity and give its fetch request the following predicate:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"team = %@", teamObject];
```

Your segue code is almost correct. Give the new view controller a `team` attribute and use this in the above predicate of its fetched results controller. You do not need any player or "playerDetails" information (they are linked to the team anyway).

Comment: Thank you!  This is working now using the Fetched Results Controller. I also take your points about the naming convention on board - I've been building it up from tutorials and not fixing things as I go. It's probably time to get all that sorted before I take it any further.